# Transform DOM Elements into Vue.js Components

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a d3.js plugin to create a complex visualization in my Vue.js  application.
I would like to apply a custom vue directive to the elements that were added by the d3 plugin.
It looks like the $compile functionality that was deprecated in vue2 is what I am looking for.

How can I dynamically change the elements in the dom to vue components?

Comment: [Vue.compile](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) is still available, but it requires a string, not elements currently in the DOM. You could play games with removing the d3 added elements,  converting it to a string and then using Vue.compile possibly, but that's a hack. Without knowing more, this is difficult to answer.

Comment: @Bert, thanks for your comment.  I considered either that or creating a shadow dom like is done in this codepen:  [https://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/gmBdKq](https://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/gmBdKq).  I rejected both those solutions.  I think there would be all sorts of side-effects from rendering twice.
In terms of "knowing more" what other details am I missing?

Comment: By letting d3 render at all you would be rendering twice anyway because Vue always compiles down to a render function. It doesn't enhance existing DOM. Traditionally with these kinds of libraries you let Vue render the DOM and enhance with the library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the property you are looking for is `$mounted`. Provide a funtion to the key `mounted`, then you can instantiate the d3 visualization.

[This is a good set of example](https://corpglory.github.io/d3vue/#/circle-mount)

The basics of `$mounted` from the above link:

```
<template>
  <svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
</template>

<script>
const d3 = require('d3');
export default {
  mounted: function() {
    // this.#el - is the root element in <template>
    // in this case it is <svg> tag
    d3.select(this.$el)
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', '250')
      .attr('cy', '150')
      .attr('r', '100')
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that's not what I'm looking for.  I have already added all of the d3 elements in the mounted function.  Now I want to take the appended items and change them to vue elements.  In the example above I would want to add a vue directive to the "circle".

Comment: `dynamically change the elements` is not clear enough I assume. You looking for creating an interactive visualization with vue.js+d3.js, am I right? Have you look at this example: https://corpglory.github.io/d3vue/#/pie-chart-local-component? This is the basics mount > watch > update

Comment: I already have an interactive visualization with d3 and vue.js that can redraw based on properties changing.  In all of those examples, none of the elements created by d3 have vue bindings, and all the updates to attributes are done through d3 code.